# Rowfilter removes the old data

Tags: c#, .net

I want to store my data on datatable and want to filter it ( e.g last 10 minutes data, or last 1 minute data )

Below code works however, if i filter the data, it removes old datas.

For example, Let's say my datagrid has last 10 minutes data and I filtered it to last 1 minute. When i do that, last 9 minutes data removes.

How can i fix that ?

```
public void getTopSQL()
        {
            dtTopSQL.Clear();
            odaTopSQL = new OracleDataAdapter(getTopSQLDetails, oradb);
            odaTopSQL.Fill(dtTopSQL);
             ugTopSQL.DataSource = null;

              for (int i = 0; i < dtTopSQL.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                bool isDupe = false;
                for (j = 0; j < dtCurTopSQL.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (dtTopSQL.Rows[i][1].ToString() == dtCurTopSQL.Rows[j][1].ToString())
                    {
                        dtCurTopSQL.Rows[j][2] = int.Parse(dtCurTopSQL.Rows[j][2].ToString()) + int.Parse(dtTopSQL.Rows[i][2].ToString());
                        isDupe = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }

                if (!isDupe)
                {
                    dtCurTopSQL.ImportRow(dtTopSQL.Rows[i]);
                }
            }

            dtCurTopSQL.DefaultView.Sort = "CountAll DESC";

            ultraGrid1.DataSource = dtCurTopSQL;

            // Here, If i use rowfilter, my old data is removing.
            dtCurTopSQL.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("SAMPLE_TIME >= '{0}'", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(lastxminutes));

            dtCurTopSQL = dtCurTopSQL.DefaultView.ToTable();

            ugTopSQL.DataSource = dtCurTopSQL;
            ugTopSQL.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it removes old data`? Does it remove from the datatable or from the grid? It doesn't remove from the data table it just apply the new filter to  the table returns filtered rows. Do you wan to combine data from old filter and new filter and show in the grid?

Comment: Hi, It removes from datatable. When i comment that line it works. As i said in my example, when i change to larger time filter, old data doesn't come up.

Comment: I see you are using infragistics ultra grid, for ultra grid you need to apply filters to grid not the data table

Comment: So, How can i change that line ?

Comment: You mean you apply first 10 minutes filter then 1 minutes filter. It removes 9 minutes data. then you 11 apply minutes filter and it still shows 1 minutes data. That's what happens ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, exactly.